# Why is it not adding the annotation onto map after my code?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, mapkit

```
NSMutableArray* annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//This is the details needed to make a new annotation.
CLLocationCoordinate2D autoCoord1;
autoCoord1.latitude = 37.78616;
autoCoord1.longitude = -122.41018;

MyAnnotation* autoAnnot1 = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];

autoAnnot1.coordinate = autoCoord1;
autoAnnot1.title = @"auto";
autoAnnot1.subtitle = @"auto";

[mapViewVC addAnnotation:autoAnnot1];

[annotations addObject:autoAnnot1];
```

I have this code that worked in another one of my mapkit apps, however I cannot seem to get an annotation `autoAnnot1` to be seen on the map at the coordinates given.

Surely the code `[mapViewVC addAnnotation:autoAnnot1];`should add that annotation to the map?

MyAnnotation.h class looks like the following:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MapKit/MapKit.h"

@interface MyAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString*              title;
    NSString*              subtitle;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D    coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy)   NSString*                 title;
@property (nonatomic, copy)   NSString*                 subtitle;

@end
```

**Below is an image showing the breakpoint and the output**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you mean `MKMapView`? What is the MyAnnotation subclass of?

Comment: Are all the outlets set?

Comment: @voromax I edited my main post for you to see what the MyAnnotation class looks like.

Comment: @andreamazz I only have 2 IBOutlets - both are used, but not for annotations

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the code you have shown us is in an initialiser method of a view controller.  At this point, the view objects have not yet been instantiated.  Your outlets are all `nil`.  Code that sets up a view should go in the `viewDidLoad` method, which is called after the view has loaded and your outlets have been hooked up.

Comment: Yes Jim, you are correct, the code is in the ViewController.m file and are also in the ViewDidLoid method therein. I should of made this clearer, so I will +1 your answer, but the question still remains. thanks

Comment: Are you certain you've hooked up the outlets?  Log `mapViewVC` to ensure it's got a value and isn't `nil`.

Comment: when you say Log MapViewVC.. do you mean NSLog(@"%@", mapViewVc)?

Comment: Yes, you need to make sure you aren't just sending messages to `nil`.

Comment: when I have written that Log code, what then? how do I use it to see if it is not just sending nil?

Comment: either run the app and look at the console log, or better yet, run in debugger and set a breakpoint on [mapViewVC addAnnotation:] line.  If mapViewVC is nil, you've found your problem.

Comment: @CSmith I have added an image showing the breakpoint in the debugger and the output when it ran. I cannot seem to find where it indicates whether its `nil` or not

Comment: The `0x00000000` to the right of `mapViewVC` shows its value.  Normally this would be a memory address, but as you can see, it's `0`, which is equivalent to `nil`.  `mapViewVC` isn't pointing to anything.  Where are you assigning to it?  If it's an outlet, double-check you have hooked it up.  IF it's not an outlet, post the code where you assign an object to it.